# What is the proper data format for this REST API?

Tags: php, rest, date

I have an API url that looks like this:

"https://cloud.XXXXXXXXX.com/api/data/XXXXXXX2017112020-804?from=2021-1-1T00:00:00&to=2021-2-26T00:00:00&averagingperiod=60&includejournal=false"

The Api, uses this Format to decode the URL and grab the data I need from the Endpoint:
The Method I use is 'GET' and the URL looks like this:
'api/data/serial?from=start time&to=end time&averagingperiod=averaging
period&includejournal=include journal'

Where api/data are standar and /serial? is the serial number of the endpoint.
(?from=) and (&to=) are the parameters I set using the [ISO 8601](http://apiux.com/2013/03/20/5-laws-api-dates-and-times/) rules.
but I need to set the time (from=) 24 hours ago (to=) the current time, for example: (?from=" . date('Y-m-d', $yesterday) . "T" . "00:00:00" . "&to=" . date("Y-m-d") . "T" . "00:00:00" .)

Date and time format is like this: (yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00)

My code looks like this:

```
    <?php
// get the timestamp of yesterday
$yesterday = strtotime('-24 Hours');

// get the timestamp of today
$today = date();

// the format we build the date in
$format = 'Y-m-d';

// get the yesterday in the specified format
$from = date($format, $yesterday);

// get today in the specified format
$to = date($format, $today);

// build the URL
$url = 'https://cloud.aeroqual.com/api/data/AQM65%2017112020-804'.'?from='.$from.'T00:00:00'.'&to='.$to.'T00:00:00'.'&averagingperiod=60&includejournal=false'.;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Cookie: .MONOAUTH=C5PBclbeW29kqexXRGTlXaHImDoLhxR/YzALxc44/SZ+KQV2XuMsZps6OJnXMSi56gjRsQ6ED6GIcH7Fk8XCoJ80IrpsTUDPO+Bmf0tVKaPZtIzpwe7ff3QqBKZLFGZK; ASP.NET_SessionId=9F89912F7F571A228B63ACEC; AWSELB=95CB9B4302EC8CCB93BD1C1D5C4630880B3D9B3CCF5F0CE3F60EF45F0604C252A119CAE7D802D28AE24434CB392308307A6E5617B4045026B161BDB6886AF9E5C0388BFFED; AWSELBCORS=95CB9B4302EC8CCB93BD1C1D5C4630880B3D9B3CCF5F0CE3F60EF45F0604C252A119CAE7D802D28AE24434CB392308307A6E5617B4045026B161BDB6886AF9E5C0388BFFED'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Question: How can I format my URL so I recieve data from 24hours ago till now(current time).
Or If anyone knows, if its possible to implement variables in cURL's URLs.

ERRORS: Upon running my php code on my server, I get Errors like:

1: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
2: VM265:7146 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @   VM265:7146

This code runs perfectly but I want to get date and time values from 24 hours ago, to current time. :

```
    <?php

$ch = curl_init();

// Configure curl as needed, depending on your application
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://cloud.aeroqual.com/api/data/AQM65%2017112020-804?from=2021-1-1T00:00:00&to=2021-2-26T00:00:00&averagingperiod=60&includejournal=false",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Cookie: .MONOAUTH=C5PBclbeW29kqexXRGTlXaHImDoLhxR/YzALxc44/SZ+KQV2XuMsZps6OJnXMSi56gjRsQ6ED6GIcH7Fk8XCoJ80IrpsTUDPO+Bmf0tVKaPZtIzpwe7ff3QqBKZLFGZK; ASP.NET_SessionId=9F89912F7F571A228B63ACEC; AWSELB=95CB9B4302EC8CCB93BD1C1D5C4630880B3D9B3CCF1DD49CB392B355F68787785EB0EA72F7A4B7F495B9BA3840A89055C0FDEAE769045026B161BDB6886AF9E5C0388BFFED; AWSELBCORS=95CB9B4302EC8CCB93BD1C1D5C4630880B3D9B3CCF1DD49CB392B355F68787785EB0EA72F7A4B7F495B9BA3840A89055C0FDEAE769045026B161BDB6886AF9E5C0388BFFED;'
  ),
));

// Do the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Cleanup
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
?>
```

Im a junior web developer and Im not really familiar with Api's, Im sorry if my question isnt formatted correctly.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Can add a question to your post?

Comment: What is currently wrong with url? It looks ok.

Comment: _“Date and time format is like this: (yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00)”_ - the date values you have in your example URL don’t appear to have the month as two digits with a leading zero though …?

Comment: `$today = date();` doesn’t `// get the timestamp of today`, it gets you an _error_ (PHP8), or a warning at least, because that function needs at least one parameter. Did you mean `time` instead of `date` perhaps?

Comment: Also, your `$url = '…'.;` has an extra dot before the semicolon, that’s also a parse error.

Comment: @CBroe I have an example code that runs perfectly with values like (yyyy-m-d), but I dont understand how to change them and make them refresable.So I dont have to state a certain time, in order to get the last 24 hour values returned by the api.

Comment: @Cbroe After grabbing the values, I want to calculate them per minute, so I need both date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer to insert edditable date and time in an API URL call is:

```
   <?php
    // Date variables for URL
    $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("now"));
    $yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));
    $to_time = date("H:m:s", strtotime("now"));
    $yesterday_time = date("H:m:s", strtotime("-1 day"));
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxxxxxxx/api/data/XXXX65%2017112020-804?from=".$yesterday."T".$yesterday_time."&to=".$to."T".$to_time."&averagingperiod=60&includejournal=false",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Cookie: .MONOAUTH=C5PBclbeW29kqexXRGTlXaHImDoLhxR/YzALxc44/SZ+KQV2XuMsZps6OJnXMSi56gjRsQ6ED6GIcH7Fk8XCoJ80IrpsTUDPO+Bmf0tVKaPZtIzpwe7ff3QqBKZLFGZK; ASP.NET_SessionId=9F89912F7F571A228B63ACEC; AWSELB=95CB9B4302EC8CCB93BD1C1D5C4630880B3D9B3CCF5F0CE3F60EF45F0604C252A119CAE7D802D28AE24434CB392308307A6E5617B4045026B161BDB6886AF9E5C0388BFFED; AWSELBCORS=95CB9B4302EC8CCB93BD1C1D5C4630880B3D9B3CCF5F0CE3F60EF45F0604C252A119CAE7D802D28AE24434CB392308307A6E5617B4045026B161BDB6886AF9E5C0388BFFED'
      ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    
    echo $response;
```